# How can I handle multiple devices as they connect and disconnect with evdev?

Tags: python, linux, python-asyncio, evdev, pyudev

I am trying to use evdev to read input events on Linux asynchronously, but I want to handle devices being connected or disconnected. To make my system relatively general and compatible with multiple devices, I want a control thread that can dispatch or cancel threads for devices when a change is detected. I have written multiple different prototypes for this, and all of them have their own issues:

The first uses the most obvious approach, but it seems the device change thread does not have permission to add others, causing a crash when devices are connected.

```
import asyncio
import evdev
import pyudev

# Function to handle device changes (connection/disconnection)
def handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks):
    current_devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    added_devices = [device for device in current_devices if device not in devices]
    removed_devices = [device for device in devices if device not in current_devices]
    devices = current_devices
    for device in added_devices:
        print(f"Added device: {device.name}")
        # Perform any necessary actions for added devices
        if "GuliKit" in device.name:
            device.grab()
            task = asyncio.create_task(print_events(device))
            device_tasks[device] = task
    for device in removed_devices:
        print(f"Removed device: {device.name}")
        # Perform any necessary actions for removed devices
        if device in device_tasks:
            task = device_tasks[device]
            task.cancel()
            del device_tasks[device]
    return devices

# Task created for each grabbed device
async def print_events(device):
    try:
        async for event in device.async_read_loop():
            print(device.path, evdev.categorize(event), sep=': ')
    except OSError:
        print(f"Device {device.name} disconnected.")
        #handle_device_changes()

# Entry point of the program
async def main():
    devices = []
    device_tasks = {}
    devices = handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks)
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(pyudev.Context())
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='input')
    def log_event(action, device):
        queue.put(handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks))
    observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(monitor, log_event)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            await queue.get()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Keyboard interrupt received.")
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        await asyncio.gather(*device_tasks.values(), return_exceptions=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(),debug=True)
```

The second was my attempt to rewrite that idea fresh, but I have no idea what's wrong with it and can't even interpret the error.

```
import evdev
import asyncio
import pyudev

# Function to handle device events
async def handle_event(device):
    async for event in device.async_read_loop():
        # Process the event here
        print("Event:", event)

# Function to handle device changes (connection/disconnection)
def handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks):
    current_devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    added_devices = [device for device in current_devices if device not in devices]
    removed_devices = [device for device in devices if device not in current_devices]
    devices = current_devices

    for device in added_devices:
        print(f"Added device: {device.name}")
        # Create a new event listener task for the added device
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        event_task = event_loop.create_task(handle_event(device))
        device_tasks[device.path] = event_task
        if "GuliKit" in device.name:
            device.grab()

    for device in removed_devices:
        print(f"Removed device: {device.name}")
        # Cancel and clean up the event listener task associated with the removed device
        event_task = device_tasks.pop(device.path)
        event_task.cancel()

    return devices

async def main():
    devices = []
    device_tasks = {}

    # Initial setup: handle device changes to set up event listeners
    devices = handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks)

    # Monitor for device changes
    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='input')

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        try:
            async for device_event in loop.run_in_executor(None, monitor.poll):
                # Handle device changes
                devices = handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The third was my attempt at using chatgpt to save this thing. I don't know what it's doing, but it is actually pretty close to working, and can keep a list of devices accurately. Except they don't report events.

```
import evdev
import selectors
import pyudev

# Function to handle device events
def handle_event(device, selector):
    for event in device.read():
        # Process the event here
        print("event")

# Function to handle device changes (connection/disconnection)
def handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks, selector):
    current_devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    added_devices = [device for device in current_devices if device not in devices]
    removed_devices = [device for device in devices if device not in current_devices]
    devices = current_devices

    for device in added_devices:
        print(f"Added device: {device.name}")
        # Create a new event listener task for the added device
        event_listener = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        event_task = selector.register(device.fd, event_listener, handle_event)
        device_tasks[device.path] = event_task

    for device in removed_devices:
        print(f"Removed device: {device.name}")
        # Destroy the event listener task associated with the removed device
        event_task = device_tasks.pop(device.path)
        selector.unregister(device.fd)

    return devices

def main():
    devices = []
    device_tasks = {}
    selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

    # Initial setup: handle device changes to set up event listeners
    devices = handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks, selector)

    # Monitor for device changes
    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='input')

    for device_event in iter(monitor.poll, None):
        # Handle device changes
        devices = handle_device_changes(devices, device_tasks, selector)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The fourth and final version is coped from a post here, though it appears to use old deprecated functionality so it does not run anymore.

```
import functools
import pyudev

from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='input')
monitor.start()

fds = {monitor.fileno(): monitor}
finalizers = []

while True:
    r, w, x = select(fds, [], [])

    if monitor.fileno() in r:
        r.remove(monitor.fileno())

        for udev in iter(functools.partial(monitor.poll, 0), None):
            # we're only interested in devices that have a device node
            # (e.g. /dev/input/eventX)
            if not udev.device_node:
                break

            # find the device we're interested in and add it to fds
            for name in (i['NAME'] for i in udev.ancestors if 'NAME' in i):
                # I used a virtual input device for this test - you
                # should adapt this to your needs
                if u'GuliKit' in name:
                    if udev.action == u'add':
                        print('Device added: %s' % udev)
                        print(udev.device_node)
                        fds[dev.fd] = InputDevice(udev.device_node)
                        break
                    if udev.action == u'remove':
                        print('Device removed: %s' % udev)
                        def helper():
                            global fds
                            fds = {monitor.fileno(): monitor}
                        finalizers.append(helper)
                        break

    for fd in r:
        dev = fds[fd]
        for event in dev.read():
            print(event)

    for i in range(len(finalizers)):
        finalizers.pop()()
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not the screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra There never were any screenshots, but I made the code inline. Hope that helps.

Comment: any update for your code ? have similar problem using thread to open an device and have problem in handling disconnection